# What is the relation between Scala and C++ traits

Tags: c++, scala

Traits is a concept used in Scala as well as in C++ (although in C++ it is more of an idiom than a concept integrated into the language). It is not obvious to me how the concepts are related though. What is the relation between Scala and C++ traits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're not related at all.

In C++, a traits class is a helper object that tells you something about a type that you can't get from the type name itself. C++ traits are actually more similar to Scala's `def foo[A:Manifest]` notation (a feature for which I don't know the proper name.)

Scala's traits are actually a lot more like C++'s multiple inheritance (though they differ in the details). I'm actually **quite** disappointed that C++'s version of multiple inheritance has the official name "multiple inheritance" (to the exclusion of all of the other variations), because the first sentence of any explanation of Scala's traits should be "Traits are a form of multiple inheritance that ..."

Comment: The `[A : Manifest]` notation is known as a "context bound"

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why they named this concept traits in scala?

Comment: @Tobbe: I *don't*. The Scala creators didn't invent the term, they just reused a concept that had already been published. You can look at the original paper that introduced the traits and see if that gives you any clue, but I didn't find anything with a quick skim. http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha02bTraits.pdf

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that C++ community often calls that pattern "type traits" rather than just "traits."